# How to override routes path helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

My route is defined like this

```
match '/user/:id' => 'user#show', :as => :user
```

If for some reason a nil ID is passed I want the route helper to return only '#' and if ID is not nil i want it to return normal path like '/user/123'.
or is there any better way to do it.
this route helper has been used in lot of places in my code so I dont want to change that. Instead I am looking for one place which will effect all instances of user_path.

Thanks

Comment: same here, anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

I did this in `app/helpers/url_helper.rb`

```
module UrlHelper
  def resource_path(resource, parameters = {})
    # my implementation
    "/#{resource.category}/#{resource.name}#{ "?#{parameters.to_query}" if parameters.present? }"
  end
end
```

I know there are ways to define such a nested route but I have a codebase using that route in several parts, as the question states.

I tried to alias old method, but was not recognised:

```
alias_method :old_resource_path, :resource_path
```

Answer (score 2):

```
module CustomUrlHelper
  def user_path(user, options = {})
    if user.nil?
      "#"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

# Works at Rails 4.2.6, for older versions try http://stackoverflow.com/a/31957323/474597
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.url_helpers_module.send(:include, CustomUrlHelper)
```

Comment: Saved the day, thanks! Normally one should adjust routes in `routes.rb` and their path helpers should always point to the same place. But sometimes you want url helpers to generate paths other than what's defined in `routes.rb`, i.e. if you're providing a front-end facade for Devise actions called via ajax.