# Change default url from Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Can we change the default 'permanent' url create from active storage to redirect to S3. Is something like rails/active_storage/representations/. I don't like the framework name in the url.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409117/change-the-activestorage-controller-path in which the maintainer states that there are no plans to make this configurable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the ActiveStorage Controller Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409117/change-the-activestorage-controller-path)

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**: 
Recently, there was an addition which makes the route prefix configurable in Rails 6: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_0_release_notes.html#active-storage-notable-changes

It's just a matter of configuration:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_storage.routes_prefix = '/whereever'
end
```

---

Unfortunately, the url is defined in ActiveStorage [routes.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/config/routes.rb) without easy means to change:

```
get "/rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename" => 
     "active_storage/blobs#show", as: :rails_service_blob
get "/rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename" => 
     "active_storage/representations#show", as: :rails_blob_representation
```

One solution *starting point* I can think of is defining your own Routes in addition and overriding the "rails_blob_representation_path" or similar

```
get "/my_uploads/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename" => 
  "active_storage/representations#show", as: :my_upload
```

and then overriding the path in a helper file and include the helper into the Named Helpers:

[How to override routes path helper in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354355/how-to-override-routes-path-helper-in-rails)

```
module CustomUrlHelper
  def rails_blob_representation(*args)
    my_upload(*args)
  end
end

# initializer etc.
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.url_helpers_module.send(:include, CustomUrlHelper)
```

The solution might need some adjustments though, I didn't tested it.

Comment: Turns out rails **5.2.2** didn't ship with route option, still waiting for it

Comment: It seems only from Rails 6, that have this option.
https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v6.0.0.beta1